# How to track user login in next auth for rendering button

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

As I found next auth provides ways of tracking the user authentication

1. useSession (Client based )
2. getServerSession(authOptions) Server Based

Now let's suppose I want to render the login and logout buttons based on the user's state
if I use clientside method it shows loading for a moment (I can't know what is client's current status is)

Then I started using getServerSession the problem is I am facing is:
I have roles for my users like User, student, and teacher
Now if  update that role using the update trigger in auth options it only appears after another reload

Now I want to know is any way that there should be no delay while knowing the client login status and also I can update the information at the time. Thanks

More importantly, what do you use personally?

I am using jwt login from backend. ( i am open to have new ideas like other alternatives of next auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (I can't know what is client's current status is

if you are not sure, just return `null`. since you are using this authenticate button in header, create its own component and if the authentication status is "loading", you return null

```
export default function HeaderAuthButton() {
  const session = useSession();
  let authButton: React.ReactNode;
  if (session.status === "loading") {
    authButton = null;
  } else if (session.data?.user) {
    authButton = (
      <div>
        <form action={signOutAction}>
          <Button type="submit">Sign Out</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    authButton = (
      <>
        <form action={signInAction}>
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
        </form>

        <form action={signInAction}>
          <Button type="submit">Sign Up</Button>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }

  return authButton;
}
```

render this component inside `Header` component

Comment: Sure this will help!
The thing is till the period I am showing the null (no button) then I will still effect. 
I mean if after null the button renders then it will make the effect in the design shift.